# Show filtering div while ng-repeat is working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a long running task that I want to show a simple div to alert the users and ask them to wait.

I have a custom filter that is taking about 10 seconds to apply. This is about three times as long as the initial page load, so that alone is an issue, but my users would be satisfied to some degree if I could show a div that warns them the task is working in memory.

I am using an ng-show="filteringTasks" variable, but it doesn't show the div because it seems that Angular is busy working on the filtering process and the user interface doesn't get updated.

```
<div ng-show="filteringTasks">Filtering Tasks...Please wait </div>
```

All of the tasks are loaded when the page initially loads, so "data" in this case is all 400+ records from the database.  Here's is the html of the ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in filteredTasks = 
    ( data | filter:searchText | statusFilter:statusOptions
    orderBy:predicate:reverse ) track by task.id " 
    on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
```

The directive "ngRepeatFinished" fires when the ng-repeat is finished. This is working correctly.

The filter is looking for one or more of five statuses (filter array) for each task. If the task.status matches the requested status and the filter is true, the task is added to the result.

Here's the filter:

```
ppApp.filter('statusFilter', [ function ( $filter ) {
return function( input, filter ) {
    if ( input ) {
        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(input, function ( task ) {
            angular.forEach( filter, function( ans, status ) {
                if ( task.status == status && ans ) {
                    result.push( task );
                }
            });
        });
        return result;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Finally, in an effort to prompt the user, I added this to the controller:

```
$scope.initialPageLoad=true; 
$scope.$watch("statusOptions['incomplete']", function() {
    if ( $scope.initialPageLoad ) {
        $scope.initialPageLoad = false;
    } else {
        alert('this may take a while');
        $scope.filteringTasks=true;
    }
});
```

The concept is to Alert the user to the long running task AND show the div by setting $scope.filteringTasks=true; One thought is to implement an infinite scroll directive and show the results as they are completed. Another is to have some kind of progress bar, but it seems like that would be useless if the interface won't even show a simple div! I really don't know why it takes so long for the filter to apply, but the code fires correctly.

How can I reliably let the users know that the ng-repeat is working behind the scenes?

Comment: Your ng-repeat is after the ng_show and it still does not display "filtering tasks?"

Comment: That's correct. The div only shows for a millisecond just before everything is complete. It does not show while ng-repeat is working.

Comment: I know it's not the question, but you did mention that you don't know why it takes so long to run, so it might be worth rewriting using just a standard for loop.  It should be considerably faster: https://jsperf.com/angular-foreach-vs-native-for-loop/3 and here are the native / jQuery tests: https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/37.

Comment: I modified the filter to user the native forEach and explicitly iterated through the filter object. I don't detect a great improvement in performance, but the idea is valid.

Comment: Does it makes sense to use **"bind once"** in the ng-repeat to improve efficiency? If so, can someone show me how to do this properly. I modified the ng-repeat to: **task in ::filteredTasks** but this doesn't seem to work. Seems like this would solve the issue by improving performance to the extent that I wouldn't need to show a div for filtering the data.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go around this is to create two html files: One with the ng-show and the other with the ng-repeat. Then use the angular stateProvider and Angular ui-route-provider to load the two html files. So initially your first html will load completely, then, your ui-router will load the second html. This could be done on user filter operation as well.

Note: This is not the primary purpose of these providers, but will do the task.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but the page is currently loaded with a few partial html files now, each loading and letting the user know by using a $scope.$emit('LOAD') and UNLOAD call.  The problem occurs when selecting the filter while everything is in memory...all of the tasks are in the $scope.data object. When the user clicks a filter, for example 'incomplete', that triggers the statusFilter and Angular starts working without firing anything else that I can trap (as far as i've been able to find).